# ( ANGULAR - TypeScript ) No puedo acceder a mis variables desde una función, si esta se ejecuta desde un setInterval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval

Tengo un componente "principal" en una aplicación Angular, que está vacía, solo la he creado para que puedan observar sin tanto código de por medio, lo que les presento como duda-problema.

declaro, un arreglo "miArreglo" de números y declaro una función para leer su tamaño y mostrarlo en consola.

En el ngOnInit || constructor ... declaro un setInterval, para que ejecute mi función cada X tiempo, pero la consola me muestra el siguiente error:

**core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at mostrarTamañoArreglo**

el error lo indica en esta linea...

`let tamañoArreglo = this.miArreglo.length;`

Pero si en vez de ejecutar un setInterval, ejecuto la funcion una unica vez como "**this.mostrarTamañoArreglo();**", la consola muestra perfectamente el tamaño del arreglo, pero necesito usar el setinterval para ejecutar la función indefinidamente cada que se cumpla un intervalo de tiempo...
Les dejo todo el codigo del componente u.u (de antemano gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer y ojalá me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo con el framework y con typescript).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-principal',
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./principal.component.css']
})
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit {

  public miArreglo:Array<number> = [1,2,3];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(this.mostrarTamañoArreglo, 2000)
  }

  public mostrarTamañoArreglo(){
    let tamañoArreglo = this.miArreglo.length;
    console.log("El tamaño de mi arreglo es: "+ tamañoArreglo);
  }

}
```

Comment: Tienes que poner dentro del ngOninit una referencia al contexto this: algo asi : let that = this; y luego dentro del ambito de setinterval en vez de poner this..... pon tath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo pongo aqui:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    setInterval(that.mostrarTamañoArreglo, 2000)
  }
```

Asi a tienes acceso al contexto padre desde setInterval, ya que este por si solo no alcanza a verlo

Comment: he correido un error otrografico, pruebalo ahora

Comment: Muchísimas gracias josanangel, claro que funcionó, de verdad que lo agradezco mucho. <3 te amo crack

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando:

```
ngOnInit() {
   let miCompn = this;
   setInterval(function () {
         miCompn.mostrarTamañoArreglo();
      }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias RobertoLeOr, resultó que si funciona de esa manera, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para ayudar <3 te amo crack